# ondevicemotion in Chrome desktop returns true

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using a "shake" function from github - and it has a detection that is browser-based javascript.

```
//feature detect
this.hasDeviceMotion = 'ondevicemotion' in window;
```

This though yields true even on Chrome on OS X.
It feels strange, since I am not willing to shake my monitor on my desktop.

Safari on OS X gives me "false" in return when testing.

I have searched but not been able to find out why Chrome decided to take this path. It bugs me.

Is there a better way to make this detection? Not all "mobile devices" has shake as well.. or does not let the browser have that capability, as it does not seem to work in windows phones.

Answer (score 0):

not really sure about your question and as well, I am just digging into its functionality, however you could use something like

```
X : <span id="varx"></span>
Y : <span id="vary"></span>
Z : <span id="varz"></span>
<script>
    window.ondevicemotion = function(event){
        var accelerationX = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
        var accelerationY = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
        var accelerationZ = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;

        document.getElementById("varx").innerHTML = accelerationX;
        document.getElementById("vary").innerHTML = accelerationY;
        document.getElementById("varz").innerHTML = accelerationZ;
    };
</script>
```

it will show this value only if the event have the accelerationIncludingGravity property, this is only available in mobile, not 100% this is what you want, you could also trigger an event asking for `if(accelerationX){//execute action}else{//execute planB}` hope this help, if it doesn't I'll be happy to learn and get some feedback.